# Linked plots without using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, interactive, ggplotly

I have created a `shiny` app to show a correlation heatmap for a large dataset. When the heatmap tiles are pressed, the corresponding scatterplots are displayed.

However, I need to make several of these apps and this exceeds my limit of publishing on `shinyapps.io`. My company is unwilling to upgrade to a paying plan. I have tried using alternative methods to publish the app such as `RInno`, to no avail (I think the app is too complex?).

If someone could please tell me how I could produce the same with `plotly` alone and NOT with `shiny`, I would be forever grateful. I believe something like `crosstalk` might be the path to take in order to link the heat map tiles to the scatter plots?

Thank you

Example from [here](https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-linked-click/).

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

# compute a correlation matrix
correlation <- round(cor(mtcars), 3)
nms <- names(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("heat"),
    plotlyOutput("scatterplot")
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("selection")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$heat <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x = nms, y = nms, z = correlation, 
            key = correlation, type = "heatmap", source = "heatplot") %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = ""), 
             yaxis = list(title = ""))
  })

  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (length(s) == 0) {
      "Click on a cell in the heatmap to display a scatterplot"
    } else {
      cat("You selected: \n\n")
      as.list(s)
    }
  })

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlotly({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "heatplot")
    if (length(s)) {
      vars <- c(s[["x"]], s[["y"]])
      d <- setNames(mtcars[vars], c("x", "y"))
      yhat <- fitted(lm(y ~ x, data = d))
      plot_ly(d, x = ~x) %>%
        add_markers(y = ~y) %>%
        add_lines(y = ~yhat) %>%
        layout(xaxis = list(title = s[["x"]]), 
               yaxis = list(title = s[["y"]]), 
               showlegend = FALSE)
    } else {
      plotly_empty()
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do but couldn't it be solution to put that what you call different apps in multiple tabs? In that way you are still just publishing one app in shinyapp.io!

Comment: @BertilBaron thanks for the idea but there are also only limited usage hours available in the free shinyapps.io, making any shiny app non-viable for our purposes.

Comment: what about hosting on your own server with the opensource shiny-server then you can host as many apps you want and you have no limited usage hours. Just an Idee. To host a server would be much cheaper than to have you all learning a new technology and you already have quite a nice app in Shiny

Comment: @BertilBaron thank you again but doesn’t that require linux? I am not technologically advanced enough to wrangle it!

Comment: to follow BertilBaron idea, you could also rent a server on Amazon Web Services (aws-EC2). It is relatively simple to install the shiny-server.

Comment: @MLavoie thanks for the suggestion. I guess all I can do is try.

Comment: You could wrap your app in a docker container and host it via shinyproxy: https://www.shinyproxy.io

Comment: On Windows even easier is running the script as a service: add  runApp(host="0.0.0.0", port=80) to your app, configure RScript.exe as target and add your script as an argument via: https://nssm.cc

Answer (score 1):

The best answer would likely be to use `crosstalk` in conjunction with `flexdashboard` https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/.

A live example of using both be found here: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/209203_02f14fea3274448bbbf8d04c99c6051b.html.

The end result is just an html page which is easy to share and use. Based on your example you shouldn't need shiny and it you should be able to use crosstalk for this use case. You'd need to step outside of R to get that functionality otherwise. Best of luck!